# How can I add custom edittext with custom action for single tap on curser?

Tags: android

I have a custom edittext where I customised it's context menu and add some custom menus to it using the function.
Setcustomactionmodecallback();
This gets triggered whenever select text with double tap or long press but I want it to trigger when I click on curser also. If currently I tap on curser it's default action mode gets triggered not my custom one.

I am new to programming/Android so sorry for mistakes.

I SOLVED THIS
I solved this by saving old curser position in OnTouch() method before passing it to super.OnTouch().
In on Click method of context menu I get new curser position with method getSelectionStart(). If both are equal then obviously u tapped on curser hence context menu should be shown.

Comment: So basically , what you want to perform?

Comment: When the user clicks on curser, the custom context menu should pop not default one. With current implementation only when user selects custom action menu pops

Comment: Can you show an image what you want to perform?

Comment: I tried to upload an image but since my reputation is below 10 I can't upload it.

Comment: Is it possible to set on click listener on curser in custom editext. If yes how can we call startcontext menu from their

Comment: You can use onTouchListener() for your editText.

Comment: How can I sat onTouchListner() for edittext's curser. Can u please show some example

Comment: I mean set onTouchListener on editText

Comment: That is not going to help. Since I use edittext touch to move curser also so if the add on touch for edittext it will override curser movement.                                                                      I want the on touch listener to curser. THAT will make sure where I want to paste text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. In the onTouch method of custom edittext I saved old curser position in private int variable. Before super.ontouch.
And in onSelection. Changed I compared old selection with new, if both are same then I must have clicked on same position.
 If I have clicked on same position then I show action menu